# What is this US accent found so often in instructional videos?

Tags: american-english, accent, register

What is this accent or register?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0E4PX3e3RE

It seems to me to include

- extensive creaky voice
- a broad range of pitch
- rising question intonation

This question is not about the merits of that vocal style. I have extensively edited this question as it appears that this vocal style is controversial, so as to avoid provoking rants.

Comment: Do I not like it? Why do you think that?

Comment: @DanSheppard I got that impression too ... probably from the connotations of the words "infuriating" and "shitload" ... the latter plainly describing not the practice of video learning but the characteristics of the intonation in the video.

Comment: But shitload is just an intensifier, isn't it? Someone can have a shitload of money without you disapproving of it, surely? And surely, other than in quite exceptional constructions, pronouns like "this" usually refer back to something that's already been mentioned? If I'd known the question was quite such a diplomatic minefield, I might have been more careful. But as no one's really explained to me what's going on, beyond it obviously being a source of internet drama, I'm not really sure what to do about it.

Comment: I am going to edit this question to make it less controversially worded, a controversy I was unaware of (and am still somewhat in the dark about). But it seems that, until I do, this question isn't going to get any quality answers.

Comment: Sounds like a restrained Valley Girl accent.  This isn't really a regional accent so much as an affectation, partly arising from the physical effects of speaking while trying to smile a big grin, partially arising from trying to sound "casual" and "friendly".

Comment: (And I do find the voice a little annoying.)

Comment: I basically thought that you disliked it for the reasons MetaEd mentions. I like the edits that have been made to the question, although it still seems a bit vague to me (I think it would be nice to have more than one example to be able to isolate the features that seem characteristic to you).

Comment: I agree, @sumelic . When I get a moment (at the weekend) I will go hunting around in my browser history for more examples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't any unusual accent in that speech. What you're referring to, though, is intonation, and one of the things you're specifically referring to is called [*vocal fry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_fry_register).

> In [vocal fry](http://mentalfloss.com/article/61552/what-vocal-fry), the vocal folds are shortened and slack so they close together completely and pop back open, with a little jitter, as the air comes through. That popping, jittery effect gives it a characteristic sizzling or frying sound.

Vocal fry has been gaining a lot of attention in the past few years, but it is not a new phenomenon, nor is it limited to women. Listen to [Noam Chomsky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2lsEVlqts0) sometime; he has it as well. One difference is that he has it a *lot*, and his register isn't all over the place, so it sounds more natural with him. But if you listen carefully, sometimes it's pretty bad. (Or he has vocal nodules. I don't know. Maybe both.)

From [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=20155):

> The following things about vocal (creak and) fry are clear:
>   - Everybody does it.
>   - Everybody has always done it.
>   - There's a widespread belief that young American women are now doing it more (than young women did in earlier decades, or than older women do now, or that men of any age do it or did it).
>   - No one has ever presented any non-anecdotal evidence that (3) is true.

(He relents a bit on that last point, however.)

Edited to add (post OP's edit): Again, I don't hear an accent. The speaker is trying - maybe a bit too hard - to speak about a chemical reaction in a not-too-monotonous tone, varying her pitch in a slightly exaggerated manner (at least that's my understanding.) The register is on the formal side - it's a teaching video. Rising question intonation - often called upspeak - is not very prominent on this video (it questionably occurs maybe twice.)

The article cited below goes into some detail about upspeak and vocal fry, as well as the negativity it has attracted.

<sub>[From Upspeak To Vocal Fry: Are We 'Policing' Young Women's Voices?](http://www.npr.org/2015/07/23/425608745/from-upspeak-to-vocal-fry-are-we-policing-young-womens-voices)</sub>

Comment: I don't hear any vocal fry at all. Vocal fry is only the 'buzz saw' at the end of sentences. I think you are labeling this as 'a young woman' and then associating that with the what many people associate with vocal fry. As @sumelic noted, it's just more highly intonated than usual.

Comment: @Mitch - I disagree. Vocal fry does not only occur at the end of sentences. It can occur at any point, and I believe it is present in spades.

Comment: I know it's unfair to police women's voices, but to my ears, *vocal fries* and *valley girl slang* are the worst kind.

Comment: This is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEqVgtLQ7qM) video talking about the phenomena with real life examples. I can definitely hear elements of vocal fry in the educational video.

Comment: Listening again, I do hear the low pitch sentence endings characteristic of what is commonly labeled 'vocal fry'. But I think using that label is not helpful here as it is associated with the tone and judgement that you are pointing out in others in your comments.

Comment: @Mitch - I don't judge people for using vocal fry (I'm sorry that it appears to you that I do so). I hardly even notice it, honestly. As I pointed out in my answer, on Language Log it is stated that "Everybody does it/has always done it..." etc. It is what it is. No judgement attached *by me*. If you can point out my negative judgement statement(s) in the answer I gave, I'd be grateful, so that I can edit it out.

Comment: @Mitch - also, I hardly think anything I said amounts to calling anyone very cheap and merely coming off as chirpy instead of interesting.

Comment: @medica My apologies. I think the term 'vocal fry' is so associated in my mind with being judgmental that even using the term seems problematic.

Comment: Woah, what's going on there. I don't think I made a value judgement in my question, so I can't accept this as I seem to have waded into a shitstorm. It seems to me there's distinctive features of this kind of voice that aren't shared by Coolio, Walter Cronkite, Amber Benson, Evlis, or Hilary Clinton, for example, (to think of some American voices I can easily bring to mind) and I was wondering what it was because I'm increasingly exposed to it due to a technology change. Hold back on the anger, folk!

Comment: I hadn't realised that "shitload" didn't travel as well as I thought. I hadn't even thought of it having negative connotations (though it's obviously informal/vulgar).

Comment: @DanSheppard - No anger here; I think it was an interesting question. I may have misread your attitude towards this speech from the statement, "distinctive shitload of creaky voice, highly variable pitch and rising questioning intonation...". Sorry if I was wrong (edited out value judgement.) As for a shitstorm, this isn't one; at least I don't see it. You should only accept answers that are helpful. I can't tell you if this helped you one way or the other.

Comment: It was mainly from the comments, @medica. I'm just kind of aware that there's someone somewhere just doing their job on the other end of this video, and I don't want to give the impression that folk are laying into them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Your referenced video has been removed by the gods of YouTube.

Comment: @Robusto   Five years on I have not the slightest memory or clue of the YouTube video deleted. It must've been good though–four upvotes! Is there any way of discovering what the title was?

Comment: Archive Internet to the rescue Title: "Vocal fry" speaking with Faith Salie https://web.archive.org/web/20150310005915/https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEqVgtLQ7qM